# Return records from a specific date

Tags: sqlite

In my table I have a column `date` which is `DATETIME` type where I save my data like `2015-10-22`. How can I select those rows which their date is older than a specific date, eg `2015-10-22`. I tried

`SELECT * FROM MYTABLE where date > '2015-10-09';`

but it doesn't return anything..  my DB is built with sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE where date > date('2015-10-09');
```